# Writing on SDCard Problem - Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a file to my SDcard in my HTC Hero phone. I create the File in my SDCard using:

File = new File(path.getAbsolutePath(), "Filename.txt");

where path is the path to my externalStorageDirectory (i.e. \sdcard)

When I log the path of this file, it does say \sdcard\filename.txt

However, when I create a fileoutputstream to write to the file, suddenly the filepath is changed to \data\data and I cannot access it.

Can someone please help clarify how I can create a File in the SDCard and then write to it?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Log.d("SDCARDPLSWORK", path.toString());
    try
    {
        myFile = new File(path.getAbsolutePath(), "SensorValues.txt");
        boolean i = myFile.createNewFile();
        Log.d("SDCARDPLSWORK", myFile.toString() + " " + i);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        Log.d("FILEANDROID", getFileStreamPath("SensorValues.txt").toString());
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is what I'm doing. The part until SDCARDPLSWORK is correct, but when it comes to the FILEANDROID log it goes to the private data storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getFileStreamPath(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath%28java.lang.String%29) reads from local directory. Your debug code is wrong.

Comment: Ohh...I thought getFileStreamPath just gets the path of a file.. it works now.. thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use  **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** for SD card path.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/yourFilename.png"
```

Comment: path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Log.d("SDCARDPLSWORK", path.toString());
        try
        {
         myFile = new File(path.getAbsolutePath(), "SensorValues.txt");
         boolean i = myFile.createNewFile();
         Log.d("SDCARDPLSWORK", myFile.toString() + " " + i);
         fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
         Log.d("FILEANDROID", myFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
         e.printStackTrace();

Comment: I would rather use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.pathSeparator + "yourFilename.png" or final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "yourFilename.png");

Comment: @Damian thanks for comment i get to learn File.pathSeparator ; - thanks

Comment: except you want File.separator not File.pathSeperator

Answer (score 0):

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() will get the root folder of sdcard.

@JAVADOC

> Applications should not directly use
>   this top-level directory, in order to
>   avoid polluting the user's root
>   namespace. Any files that are private
>   to the application should be placed in
>   a directory returned by
>   Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the
>   system will take care of deleting if
>   the application is uninstalled. Other
>   shared files should be placed in one
>   of the directories returned by
>   getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String).

/data/data/... this location is used to store files for your package, so try the codes below:

```
File path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(); // get your private folder
Log.d("SDCARDPLSWORK", path.toString());
File myFile;
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    myFile = new File(path.getAbsolutePath(),
            "SensorValues.txt");
    boolean i = myFile.createNewFile();
    Log.d("SDCARDPLSWORK", myFile.toString() + " " + i);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    Log.d("FILEANDROID", getFileStreamPath("SensorValues.txt")
            .toString());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```